# image going over page limits

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and html and I'm doing my hero section right now but when I add a image to the hero section the image is loaded way beyond the header limits. How can I make so everything in the page is aligned to the header and doesn't go over "boundaries".

example: https://prnt.sc/10wn3io

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: we need a code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `width` and `margin: 0 auto;` to the containers. And also you should set `object-fit: cover` to resize your image.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

body {
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}

.menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container menu">
    Menü
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_50917877588_9db3484f10_c_640_360_nofilter.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

If this solution does not work, we can find a better solution if you share your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
/* if you want to cover the background by image then
add `background-size:cover;` */
```

}